# Limit of sequence of sets $S_n = \{\frac{1}{n}\}$

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a sequence of sets
 $$S_n = \left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$$
And I want to know $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$.

Intuition tells me that as with usual limits $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = \left\{0\right\}$. But by definition from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1490451/724635) $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = S$ iff
$$\forall x\; \exists N\in\mathbb N\; \forall n>N : x\in S\Leftrightarrow x \in S_n$$

Obviously $0$ will not appear in any $S_n$, when $n$ is finite.

Does that mean that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ doesn't exist? And if yes, then is there some other type/definition of limit that will make $S_n$ converge to $\{0\}$?

Comment: The limit of any disjoint sequence of sets is empty.

Comment: According to the linked definition the limit is the empty set. But you really should check the definition used in your book (or wherever this question came from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the set theoretic sense the limit of any disjoint sequence of sets is empty. However $S_n$ does converge to $\{0\}$ w.r.t the Hausdorff metric.  Ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance

Comment: Thanks. I think Hausdorff convergence is what I was looking for