# Increasing limit in sequence of set

Tags: probability-theory, limits, measure-theory, set-theory

I am reading Foundations of Modern Probability by Kallenberg and stuck on the meaning of increasing limit $A_n\uparrow A$ for sequence of set (pageno 1), I read this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490438/what-is-meant-by-limit-of-sets), but I have to confirm that it means

for some n

$A = \bigcap_{m\geq n}\bigcup_{k\geq m} A_k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\ A_n\uparrow A\ $ means that:

- The sequence $\ \big\{A_n\big\}\ $ of sets is monotone increasing—that is $\ A_j\subseteq A_k\ $ for all $\ j,k\ $ with $\ k\ge j\ $, and
- $\ A=\bigcup_\limits{k=1}^\infty A_k\ $

As it happens, in these circumstances, $\ A=\bigcup_\limits{k=m}^\infty A_k\ $ for all $\ m\ ,$ and so
\begin{align}
\bigcap_{m=n}^\infty\bigcup_\limits{k=m}^\infty A_k&=\bigcap_{m=n}^\infty A\\
&=A
\end{align}
not just for *some* $\ n\ ,$ but for *all* $\ n\ .$ However, if the sequence $\ \big\{A_n\big\}\ $ is *not* monotone increasing, and $\ B\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\bigcap_\limits{m=n}^\infty\bigcup_\limits{k=m}^\infty A_k\ ,$ then it's *not* true that $\ A_n\uparrow B\ $(and $\ B\ $ will generally depend on $\ n\ $).

Thus, while it *follows from* $\ A_n\uparrow A\ $ that $\ A=\bigcap_\limits{m=n}^\infty\bigcup_\limits{k=m}^\infty A_k\ $ for some $\ n\ ,$ those statements are not equivalent.

Comment: First apology for modifying my question, I have reverted it to the original question. Actually I was confusing $A_n \uparrow A$ with limit on a new sequence which start from $n$ of the original sequence $\{A_n\}$. My confusion was cleared after checking monotone class definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem) which is exactly your answer.

Comment: Could you recommend a book containing these basic operations definition?